# Can't upload an image to my domain

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using my own domain for developing ideas and basic Web Pages. I designed a  element that had an image on its background as you see here:

```
background:url(img/myImage.png);
```

I made a jQuery effect that changed the image to one to another, so I take my background property like this:

```
var prev_value = $(this).css('background-image');
var patt=/\"|\'|\)/g;
prev_value = prev_value.split('/').pop().replace(patt,'');
```

And when you do:

```
console.log(prev_value);
```

it writes on the FireBug console the name of my image without writing the whole route of it.

When I try to upload my code using FileZila to my private domain, my images disappear. But the thing is that I can't even see the image at first load. It seems as if it doesn't upload the images properly.

The structure of my codes is:

```
(Folder)img
(Code)index.html
(Code)jquery_effects.js
(Code)style.css
```

Can anybody help me to see why when I upload my images to my domain I can't see them??

Thank you a lot in advance.

Comment: What is the full path to the image you expect to see?

Comment: url("file:///H:/DATOS%20VELL/Sonia%20XP/Treball/jQuery/Prova%20Web/img/BNimg10.png")
The one directly to my computer. The thing is I don't know how it will work if I want to upload it to my domain...

Comment: Can you please display the html code that displays the image.

Comment: <span class="circle-styled pos12" style="background:url('img/BNimg15.png'); opacity:0.25;"></span>

Comment: Your span is empty so it may not display at all.  Consider replacing it with a div and setting a width and height.

Comment: It may be due to file permissions, right-click the file with Firebug and make sure everyone has read permission.

Comment: @Surreal Dreams, thanks, you were right. Can you post it as an answer so I can rate you?

Comment: @Sonhja- I'm glad I could help, the answer is posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your span is empty so it may not display at all- it will size itself to fit its contents. Consider replacing it with a div and setting a width and height.  That should give you a more reliable and intuitive result.